# How to combine Service worker Pre-fetching with fetching across navigations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, asynchronous, service-worker

I'm trying to use " Pre-fetching" and fetch "collect"  techniques to cache js, CSS, and stuffs on a SPA application.

To  pre-fetching scripts I have tried a code very like this snippet:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
      var now = Date.now();
    
      var urlsToPrefetch = [
        'static/pre_fetched.txt',
        'static/pre_fetched.html'
      ];
    
         
      event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.prefetch).then(function(cache) {
          var cachePromises = urlsToPrefetch.map(function(urlToPrefetch) {
            var url = new URL(urlToPrefetch, location.href);
            url.search += (url.search ? '&' : '?') + 'cache-bust=' + now;
           var request = new Request(url, {mode: 'no-cors'});
            return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
              if (response.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error('request for ' + urlToPrefetch +
                  ' failed with status ' + response.statusText);
              }
    
              return cache.put(urlToPrefetch, response);
            }).catch(function(error) {
              console.error('Not caching ' + urlToPrefetch + ' due to ' + error);
            });
          });
    
          return Promise.all(cachePromises).then(function() {
            console.log('Pre-fetching complete.');
          });
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error('Pre-fetching failed:', error);
        })
      );
    });
```

Full code can be checked [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/prefetch/)

After pre-fetching, I have almost all critical scripts on cache (such as angular.js, modules and controllers and maybe some jqueries), so, I do a fetch event to collect all others scripts that load by require.js asynchronously.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    if (event.request.method === "GET" && testes_to_know_if_it_area_a_js_or_css) {
        event.respondWith(
                caches.match(event.request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        loggger && console.log('From Cache', event.request.url);
                        return response;
                    }

                    // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
                    // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
                    // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
                    // to clone the response
                    var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

                    return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                            function (response) {
                                // Check if we received a valid response
                                if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                                    return response;
                                }

                                // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                                // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                                // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                                // to clone it so we have 2 stream.
                                var responseToCache = response.clone();

                                caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES['general-cache'])
                                        .then(function (cache) {
                                            try {
                                                loggger && console.log('Add to Cache', event.request.url);
                                                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                                            } catch (e) {
                                                console.error(e);
                                            }
                                        });

                                return response;
                            }
                    );
                })
                );
    }
});
```

Sorry, I don't found the original script that I based to build this one.

Both, are working very well, but not as expected. The second fetch add it to cache again, I Think it's because `caches.match(event.request)` doesn't really match. So, I put a console to see both request objects, the synthetic created by pre-fetch and the cloned from fetch.

- The synthetic:
  [image]
- The cloned:
  [image]

So, I'm not sure if I can overwrite these properties to synthetic be same as cloned, can I do that safely? How can I solve that?

PS: This code isn't run as common scripts. The snippet was just to organize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not found any reference to confirm my solution, but, its works.

The solution was create a 2 different caches and "Normalize" the request cloning it into a syntetic request, removing all references, keeping only the basic:

```
var CURRENT_CACHES = {
    'prefetch-cache': 'prefetch-cache-v' + CACHE_VERSION, //Prefetch cach
    'general-cache': 'general-cache-v' + CACHE_VERSION,
};
```

The `prefetch-cache` is responsible to store all files that I want to prefetch on  my service worker and the general-cache is for all other files(It make sense when you have a SPA and want to accumulate some requests like translation files, js components, css and other stuffs).

You can make an array with URI of all files that you want to prefetch:

```
var urlsToPrefetch = [
    //JS
    "plugin/angular/angular.min.js", "plugin/requirejs/require.min.js","app/main.js","app/app.js","app/includes.js"
    //CSS
    ,"styles/css/print.css","styles/css/bootstrap.css","styles/css/fixes.css",
    //Html
    ,"app/layout/partials/menu.tpl.html",  "app/layout/public.tpl.html",
    //JSON
    ,"app/i18n/languages.json","app/i18n/pt-br.json", "app/i18n/en.json"
];
```

And into install event you should create new Requests of all files from this array and store into prefetch-cache:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    logger && console.log('Handling install event:', event);

    //var now = Date.now();

    // All of these logging statements should be visible via the "Inspect" interface
    // for the relevant SW accessed via chrome://serviceworker-internals   
    if (urlsToPrefetch.length > 0) { 
        logger && console.log('Handling install event. Resources to prefetch:', urlsToPrefetch.length , "resources");
        event.waitUntil(
                caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES['prefetch-cache']).then(function (cache) {
            var cachePromises = urlsToPrefetch.map(function (urlToPrefetch) {
                urlToPrefetch +=  '?v=' + CACHE_VERSION;
                // This constructs a new URL object using the service worker's script location as the base
                // for relative URLs.
                //var url = new URL(urlToPrefetch + '?v=' + CACHE_VERSION, location.href);
                var url = new URL(urlToPrefetch, location.href);
                // Append a cache-bust=TIMESTAMP URL parameter to each URL's query string.
                // This is particularly important when precaching resources that are later used in the
                // fetch handler as responses directly, without consulting the network (i.e. cache-first).
                // If we were to get back a response from the HTTP browser cache for this precaching request
                // then that stale response would be used indefinitely, or at least until the next time
                // the service worker script changes triggering the install flow.
                //url.search += (url.search ? '&' : '?') + 'v=' + CACHE_VERSION;

                // It's very important to use {mode: 'no-cors'} if there is any chance that
                // the resources being fetched are served off of a server that doesn't support
                // CORS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).
                // In this example, www.chromium.org doesn't support CORS, and the fetch()
                // would fail if the default mode of 'cors' was used for the fetch() request.
                // The drawback of hardcoding {mode: 'no-cors'} is that the response from all
                // cross-origin hosts will always be opaque
                // (https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cross-origin-resources)
                // and it is not possible to determine whether an opaque response represents a success or failure
                // (https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/14).
                var request = new Request(url, {mode: 'no-cors'});
                return fetch(request).then(function (response) {
                    logger && console.log('Add to Cache (Prefetch)', url.href);


                    if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                        throw new Error('request for ' + urlToPrefetch +
                                ' failed with status ' + response.statusText);
                    }
                    //var responseToCache = response.clone();

                    // Use the original URL without the cache-busting parameter as the key for cache.put().
//                    return cache.put(urlToPrefetch, responseToCache);
                    return cache.put(urlToPrefetch, response);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    logger && console.error('Not caching ' + urlToPrefetch + ' due to ' + error);
                });
            });

            return Promise.all(cachePromises).then(function () {
                logger && console.log('Pre-fetching complete.');
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
           logger && console.error('Pre-fetching failed:', error);
        }));
    }

    // Perform install steps
//    if (urlsToPrefetch.length > 0) {
//        event.waitUntil(
//                caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES['perma-cache'])
//                .then(function (cache) {
//                    return cache.addAll(urlsToPrefetch);
//                })
//                );
//    }
    // `skipWaiting()` forces the waiting ServiceWorker to become the
    // active ServiceWorker, triggering the `onactivate` event.
    // Together with `Clients.claim()` this allows a worker to take effect
    // immediately in the client(s).
    return self.skipWaiting();
});
```

For all others files that will be stored in cache in future you must declare it into fetch event listener and store this requests into general-cache:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    //console.log(event);
    if (event.request.method === "GET") {
        var qSFilter = "" + ((event.request.url).split('?'))[0];//Filtrar Quetry Stirng
        //console.log(event.request.url, qSFilter, qSFilter.split(CACHE_SCOPE), CACHE_SCOPE);
        var leUrl = (qSFilter.split(CACHE_SCOPE))[1];
        //Is possible to implement some logic to skip backend calls and other uncachable calls
        if (/^(app|style|plugin).*(js|css|html|jpe?g|png|gif|json|woff2?)$/.test(leUrl)
                || /^backend\/server\/file\/i18n\/((?!client).+)\//.test(leUrl)
                || /^backend\/server\/static\/images\/.*$/.test(leUrl)
                || /^backend\/server\/static\/style.*$/.test(leUrl)
                ) {
            var url = new URL(leUrl + '?v=' + CACHE_VERSION, location.href);
            var synthetic = new Request(url, {mode: 'no-cors'});
            //console.log(event.request,response.clone(),synthetic);
            event.respondWith(
//                    caches.match(event.request)
                    caches.match(synthetic)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        // Cache hit - return response
                        if (response) {
                            logger && console.log('From Cache', event.request.url);
                            return response;
                        }

                        // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
                        // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
                        // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
                        // to clone the response
                        var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

                        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                                function (response) {
                                    // Check if we received a valid response
                                    if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                                        return response;
                                    }

                                    // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                                    // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                                    // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                                    // to clone it so we have 2 stream.
                                    var responseToCache = response.clone();

                                    caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES['general-cache'])
                                            .then(function (cache) {
                                                try {
                                                    logger && console.log('Add to Cache', event.request.url, qSFilter,leUrl);
                                                    cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                                                } catch (e) {
                                                    console.error(e);
                                                }
                                            });

                                    return response;
                                }
                        );
                    })
                    );
        }
    }
});
```

The full working script could be accessed here:
https://gist.github.com/LeonanCarvalho/0527526a6b784b23facf56fa3cc12d22